# hda-codec and hda-intel issues

Tags: linux, arch-linux, intel

I use Arch Linux 3.5.6-1-ARCH and since ever I get a lot of those error messages in dmesg on my HP Pavilion dv6 (pure systemd):

```
[   72.137821] hda-intel: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x370100
[   72.137822] hda-intel: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x370100
[   72.137823] hda-intel: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x370100
[   72.137825] hda-intel: spurious response 0x0:0x0, last cmd=0x370100
[   74.143253] hda-intel: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x00270d00
[   75.146190] hda-intel: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x00270d00
[   76.592168] hda-intel: spurious response 0x1002aa01:0x0, last cmd=0x170503
```

here is my complete dmesg output: https://gist.github.com/3857722

here is my journalctl output: https://gist.github.com/3857736

here is my lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Madison [Radeon HD 5000M Series]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Redwood HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5000 Series]
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
7f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
7f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
7f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
7f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
7f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
7f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

I've noticed that when those errors appears my CPU temp grow up, but top and powertop doesn't detect any process "eating" lot of CPU...

Here is my powertop "tunable":

```
 Bad           Wireless Power Saving for interface wlan0                                                              
 Bad           Enable SATA link power management for /dev/sda
 Bad           NMI watchdog should be turned off
 Bad           VM writeback timeout
 Bad           Enable Audio codec power management
 Bad           Autosuspend for USB device Optical USB Mouse [Logitech]
 Bad           Autosuspend for USB device Broadcom 2070 Bluetooth [Broadcom Corp]
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet co
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
 Bad           Wake-on-lan status for device eth0
 Good          Bluetooth device interface status
 Good          Autosuspend for USB device 2SF022 [DB04008LAZTM5B]
 Good          Autosuspend for USB device EHCI Host Controller [usb1]
```

Any help is appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: thank you @don_crissti, I don't know how could I miss it... adding `options snd_hda_intel probe_only=0,1` in a `snd_hda_intel.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d` seems to solve my issue. But I'll wait few days to be sure before to post that as a solution. Now I'll discover how to get rid of all that `Runtime PM for PCI Device` bad PowerTop's messages. Many thanks!

Comment: no way... since the last Arch Linux upgrade (it's Xorg fault I think) those errors are come back at every boot... what I could check? I've enabled Audio codec power management too adding `options snd-hda-intel power_save=1` in `/etc/modprobe.d/powersave.conf` and related PowerTop `bad` is now `good`... but the errors are still there